# How to process GET operation (CRUD) in go lang via Postman?

Tags: http, go, http-get, postman

I want to perform a get operation. I am passng  name as a resource to the URL. 
The URL I am hitting in Postman is : `localhost:8080/location/{titan rolex}` ( I chose the GET method in the dropdown list)
On the URL hit in Postman, I am executing the GetUser func() with body as:

```
func GetUser(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

}
```

Now I wish to get the resource value i.e 'titan rolex' in the GetUser method. 
How can I achieve this in golang?

In main(), I have this :

```
http.HandleFunc("/location/{titan rolex}", GetUser)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is binding the *complete* path `/location/{titan rolex}` to be handled by `GetUser`.

What you really want is to bind `/location/<every possible string>` to be handled by one handler (e.g. `LocationHandler`).

You can do that with either the standard library or another router. I will present both ways:

1. Standard lib:

   ```
   import (
       "fmt"
       "net/http"
       "log"
   )

   func locationHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       name := r.URL.Path[len("/location/"):]
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "Location: %s\n", name)
   }

   func main() {
       http.HandleFunc("/location/", locationHandler)
       log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
   }
   ```

   Note however, more complex paths (such as `/location/<every possible string>/<some int>/<another string>`) will be tedious to implement this way.
2. The other way is to use [github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter), especially if you encounter these situations more often (and have more complex paths).

   Here's an example for your use case:

   ```
   import (
       "fmt"
       "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
       "net/http"
       "log"
   )

   func LocationHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "Location: %s\n", ps.ByName("loc"))
   }

   func main() {
       router := httprouter.New()
       router.GET("/location/:loc", LocationHandler)

       log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
   }
   ```

   Note that `httprouter` uses a slightly different signature for handlers. This is because, as you can see, it passes these parameters to the functions as well.

Oh and another note, you can just hit `http://localhost:8080/location/titan rolex` with your browser (or something else) - if that something else is decent enough, it will URLEncode that to be `http://localhost:8080/location/titan%20rolex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights @mrd0ll4r . 
I am able to fetch the data now. So basically I think that r.GET is better option than HnadleFunc.

Comment: It is basically the same - what I did was adding the `httprouter` in between, who decies what handler to use.

Comment: @mrd0ll4r the way to do this with just the std lib is to register a handler for `/location/` which will match `/location/titan rolex` short example http://play.golang.org/p/fyJVDqL2Ox long example https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/